# What words, phrases, or noises are appropriate for backchanneling in Esperanto?

Tags: speaking, language

Backchanneling is the feedback that listeners give to show that they are listening.

Answer (score 7):

This is often a culture-dependent question because often people make "listening noises" without even thinking about it. You will find this the case even with very fluent speakers. A few ideas to get you started:

- jes
- bone
- daŭrigu
- mi aŭdas
- interese
- kaj poste?
- ĉu?
- vere?

If you find your speaking partner reacting in unexpected ways to certain phrases, use another phrase. Even "mmm" and "uh huh" will work.